# NSNumberFormatter returning scientific notation when set to decimal style

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumber

I am trying to save and retrieve `MPMediaPlaylists` using their `persistentId`s, which are NSNumbers. Because of my class setup, I need to save these ids as strings. However, when I try to convert the strings back in to NSNumbers, they come out in scientific notation rather than decimal.  Here is my code:

```
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(playlists[indexPath.row].id)
println(playlists[indexPath.row].id)
println(number)
```

The .id is a property of my Playlist object, which is a string.  For one playlist, this outputs:

```
13818827612659406491
1.381882761265941e+19
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

*Double has a precision of at least 15 decimal digits, whereas the precision of Float can be as little as 6 decimal digits. The appropriate floating-point type to use depends on the nature and range of values you need to work with in your code.*

Your number has more than 15 digits of precision.

```
let str = "13818827612659406491" // 20 digits
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
let number = numberFormatter.numberFromString(str) //13,818,827,612,659,400,000.0 - 15 significant digits
```

Also from the documentation:

*NSDecimalNumber, an immutable subclass of NSNumber, provides an object-oriented wrapper for doing base-10 arithmetic. An instance can represent any number that can be expressed as mantissa x 10^exponent where mantissa is a decimal integer up to **38 digits** long, and exponent is an integer from –128 through 127.*

which is why the OP's own answer works.

Comment: I need to retrieve an `MPMediaPlaylist` item using an `MPMediaQuery` with the id. Also from Apple's documentation regarding the `MPMediaPlaylistPropertyPersistentID` property: "The persistent identifier for the playlist. Value is an NSNumber object containing a UInt64_t (unsigned long long)."

Comment: Strange! try the following in Playground...

let ui:UInt64 = 13818827612659406491 // not what you expect!

Comment: That *is* very strange... How can a UInt have a negative sign?

Comment: @Garrett When overflown. Probably a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Facts:

1. Your number is not a decimal number
2. `NSNumberFormatter` will make your strings localized (e.g. localized decimal point).
3. `NSNumberFormatter` considers all numbers as doubles so you will always lose precision.

Answer:

Don't use `NSNumberFormatter`, it won't work here at all.
To get the string from number, use simply `-[NSNumber stringValue]`.
To get the number from string use `-[NSString longLongValue]` or `NSScanner` directly.

The best solution, of course, is to leave the id as `NSNumber`. Converting it to a string and back just causes problems.

Comment: Swift doesn't seem to allow `longLongValue` on a `String`

Comment: @Garrett Yeah, it's only on an `NSString`. `String` and `NSString` aren't always interchangeable. Since Swift doesn't have its own frameworks yet, you will have to work with Obj-C objects, including NSStrings...

Answer (score -2):

I found my answer:

```
let number = NSDecimalNumber(string: playlists[indexPath.row].id)
```

That works just fine. Not sure why it works when the NSNumberFormatter didn't...

Comment: "Not sure why it works when the NSNumberFormatter didn't" I'd suggest reading the other answers and comments that explain exactly why it didn't work.

Comment: I understand why the others didn't work. But I don't how this one worked despite that.

Comment: @Garrett Because `NSDecimalNumber` uses decadic (10-base) arithmetic (not binary) so it is not losing precision. It has also its own parser so there is a direct conversion string -> number while `NSNumberFormatter` always converts the string to a `double` first. Also, you don't ask it to format it as a decimal number...